# Effect of an isolation transformer on leakage current

Tags: current, transformer, isolation, earth

How do isolation transformers affect the leakage current through protective earth in a system?

Scenario 1: Mains is directly connected to circuit. Metal enclosure has a protective earth connection to building earth. Current passing through earth conductor = I1.

Scenario 2: Line and neutral from mains are isolated from circuitry via an isolation transformer. Earth connection from enclosure to building earth remains as earlier. Current through earth conductor = I2.

I2 < I1. Is this right? Why is this?
The explanation I was given was that its a simple matter of KCL. The current leaving the isolation transformer's secondary line has to return(node current equation) via the secondary neutral and hence the leakage current is lesser(in ideal cases 0).

On the other hand, if the system is powered directly by the mains, the current has the option of returning via the earth wire or the neutral wire as they have a galvanic connection at the mains end.

Firstly, is this right? If it is, then my problem with this explanation is this:

I understand that the leakage current arises because of the coupling between the circuitry and the earth connection, in this case the metal enclosure(which has a earth conductor to the building earth). *Now this coupling should solely be decided by the dielectric properties of the material(s) that is separating the circuitry from the enclosure(earth). How will an isolation transformer affect this coupling(and hence the leakage current)?* All the isolation transformer can do is to block out common mode noise on the primary to the secondary. So will I1 - I2 = common mode noise? Or am I oversimplifying this?

This is a conceptual question and I'm just trying to understand the basics here.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. Transformers don't "source" energy at all, they merely convert it. It sounds like you're trying to talk about the common-mode noise that couples across the isolation barrier. That is controlled by minimizing the coupling capacitance across the isolation barrier, and is entirely AC in nature.

Comment: Incidentally, in basically every mains-powered piece of equipment out there, the protective earth does *nothing* the great majority of the time (and some equipment doesn't even have an earth connection!). Realistically, there should be only micro/nano amps of current on the protective earth line, if any.

Comment: @ConnorWolf No, I am not referring to the common-mode noise. What I meant was that when a system is connected directly to the mains, the wires being line, neutral and earth; at a given instant, the current travelling through line is equal to the current through netural + current through earth. The last one is what we define as leakage current for a system. This leakage current can be controlled by using an isolation transformer. I am trying to understand how.

Comment: In that case, the isolation transformer breaks the circuit outside of the protective earth. As such, no current can flow, because there isn't a complete circuit.

Comment: Basically, there is no current-path *through* the isolation transformer.

Comment: Well, that depends on the transformer. The point is, I can break that earth connection, and let the whole thing float, and it will still work fine.

Comment: You mean the leakage current is ideally going to be zero?

Comment: Yes. In a perfect transformer. As it is, you can optimize transformers for isolation, or for power-efficency, or for price, but not all three.

Comment: Sorry, I have some weird mental block that when you say leakage current, I automatically think DC. The leakage you are talking about is AC capacitive coupling between the windings, generating a common-mode AC voltage between the primary and the secondary of the transformer, correct?

Comment: I am talking about leakage current through the protective earth. For example the current through the earth cable of a 3 core mains cable. This could be indeed the common mode noise, but wouldn't it be observed without common mode noise as well?

Comment: That is my point. There is no electrical connection between the primary and the secondary of the isolation transformer. As such, there can be no DC path, and the only AC path is capacitive, and must as such be common-mode (since the primary and secondary are low-impedance in comparison to the isolation resistance across which the capacitive coupling occurs).

Comment: I'm ignoring DC leakage across the isolation resistance here, since it's safe to assume it's in the giga-ohms, assuming the transformer is properly built.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I'll try to explain my question better. Consider a system being powered by AC mains without any isolation transformer. The system(think industrial equipment, not a pcb) has a metal enclosure to which I connect my protective earth cable which goes back to mains. Since the metal enclosure has a substantial voltage wrt earth, there will be current flowing through this conductor and this I think is not related to noise. Adding an isolation transformer(ac-ac) to this setup between the AC mains and the system will apparently reduce this current through the conductor. I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Rustin "*Since the metal enclosure has a **substantial voltage** wrt earth*..." How, and why? Something is wrong with this picture. Any enclosure that has substantial voltage with reference to earth, is a serious risk to human life. Are you sure you are not confusing circuit ground with building earth? Circuit ground of a line-isolated device should never be connected to the enclosure - and yes, I am referring to industrial electronics, which is what I work with.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Substantial for a measurable current to be flowing through the protective earth conductor. Not substantial enough to harm a human life if the earth connection happens to come off(which is what you referred to I guess). I am indeed referring to protective earth/building earth and not circuit ground. Now, as you would know, there are restrictions on the current value that can flow through this conductor. One of the ways to reduce this current is to use an isolation transformer. I understand its just the isolation at work, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: I might be missing a basic concept here, I just can't point it out. I must also say that I have a predominantly 'electronics' background and protective earthing is relatively new to me.

Comment: @Rustin. The whole point of "earth" is in the event of a fault the Hot or Live is shorted to earth conducting the energy away from people. In the real world the capacitive(and possibly inductive) coupling does mean there can be a current flow in the earth wire. The designer should not allow current to flow through the earth wire by design. The earth is there to "catch" stray wires, screws, dirt, sparks and arcs. Indeed the isolation between earth and neutral is tested on equipment. When the isolation breaks down you have a fault. At this point the fuse should blow or GFCI trip.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh For example, the current through the conductor will ultimately be decided by the potential between the metal enclosure and building earth. How does adding an isolation transformer reduce this voltage level?

Comment: @Rustin This brings us back to where we started: Why exactly would there be any significant *potential between the metal enclosure and building earth*, except in a fault condition?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh would like to use Spoon's comment to explain. As he mentioned, in a practical scenario there is going to be some coupling between the circuitry and the protective earth. While designing, we try to minimize this coupling as much as possible. It is however not perfect, and there will be some current flow through the protective earth. It is never going to be zero and it will be measurable(say in the hundreds of uA). So there is a measurable potential difference wrt to earth.

Comment: @Spoon Building on your explanation, the leakage current will be decided by the coupling between the circuitry and the earth. How will this coupling be reduced by adding an isolation transformer? The isolation transformer can only take care of the coupling between the live/neutral and earth wires, right?

Comment: @Rustin Power supplies (and other noisy gadgets) have AC-side EMI filters with Y-capacitors which are connected between line or neutral and earth. These deliberately leak current via earth, and there are standards which dictate how much leakage is tolerable (3.5mA for office gear, less for medical stuff IIRC). Most of the isolation transformers I've dealt with maintain a through earth connection, but have no galvanic connection between neutral and earth on the 'isolated' output side - *this* is the isolation that's provided.

Comment: @Madmanguruman Point about the EMI filters with Y-capacitors - perfectly clear. So is the deliberate leakage of current - this is the common mode noise on the live wires. Now for the lack of galvanic connection, as i mentioned in the question, at the very basic, this is just KCL. The only return path is this 'secondary neutral' and so the current has to return via this path leading to lower leakage current. Is that it?

Comment: An Isolation transformer added between the mains and a device will float the device and I see how this breaks the earth loop and reduces leakage drasticly because there is now no return path. Why would this be desirable? Certainly it is done when using scopes on the mains side of SMPS circuits as the probe is often at earth. (Hands up if you've toasted a scope?, educational...) If it's double insulated fine, But if you use this method to get a piece of equipment working that is faulty under normal mains connection, I for one will be walking/running away for a looong coffee....

Comment: Answering "the leakage current will be decided by the coupling between the circuitry and the earth. How will this coupling be reduced by adding an isolation transformer? " You no longer have an earth connection if you disconnect the earth. it's what @Olin Lathrop said... I wasn't paying attention ..my appologies

Comment: @Rustin I like the re-write of the question. Protective Earth works by providing a low impeadence path essentiall back to the Neutral of the utility transformer supplying say a house. If the device is powered by the isolation transformer the power driving the device is now effectivly sourced from the transformer secondries. With no path the current won't flow with respect to the primay of the isolation transformer. The key is current paths as you stated. It comes down to ... if there is a current path you will see leakage, break the path and there is no leakage. It's all potentials and paths.

Answer (score 3):

The point of a isolation transformer is to break any common mode connection to the rest of the world.  This therefore allows *one* connection to the rest of the world that won't draw any current.  Usually you try to not have any such connection, so that a accidental connection (you touching a live wire with one hand while grabbing a metal drain pipe with the other, for example) is the first connection and therefore safe.

A common mistake people make when using a isolation tranformer is to forget that connecting a oscilloscope usually means connection some point to real earth ground.  That by itself is OK since it is only a single connection.  However, now the circuit is no longer isolated and significant current can flow between some part of the circuit and a metal pipe, for example.

Comment: I have edited the question to include details from the discussion in comments. I'm trying to understand a situation in which the earth conductor is not removed from the circuit/metal enclosure. Only the line, neutral are isolated between primary and secondary. The earth connection is directly from the metal enclosure to the building earth.